# Unable to group by highlighted column in the snapshot highlighted, this is a text field and not present in the data source query

Tags: report, rdlc

[Report snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoKuT.jpg)

Hi Folks,

Can any one suggest how to group by the highlighted column in the attached Report snapshot...please note that this a text field and not present in the source query. This is a RDLC Report...finally I want to show Patients data in Direct Referrals row by row as in Central & HQ locations.